# Using codeigniter library in a native Php Code decrypt not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, native

Silly question from a newbie user. Hope all is well first and I have a question. There are many codeiginter user that thinks that codeigniter is the best when coding in php. I don't blame them and totally respect their point of view. I have been a native Php programmer for sometime and I just wanted to ask if it is possible to use a codeigniter Library for my native Php project.

I tried researching but I guess no one actually tried over the net so I'm asking this one.

I was actually trying to use the encryption library of code igniter for my Pure php.

Is there a way for this?

Here's what @barudo told me

```
<?php

include_once("enryption.php");
$key = '5fea190fb9cdbfdb7e2b69276df4c544';

function log_message($message)
{
error_log($message);
}

function config_item($what)
{
//just a placeholder...
}
$cipher = new CI_Encryption();
$cipher->initialize(
[
    'driver'=>'openssl',
    'key' => $key
]
);
$plaintext = 'bd410a21c2498e83109224b38f80743b83eafcb321c7ab56e027fb84ab76708b3797ad320d011520e9811aadc67c7d13ccf9bfb45e91d757004b25efc9717266qTmIbwsXDpDtzMbQur4+KwWt7zlmvTrq8B19rDMNmR4=';
//$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);

//echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertext . "\n"."</br>";
echo 'plaintext: ' . $cipher->decrypt($plaintext) . "\n";
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you try copying the encryption library to your code?

Comment: Yes. Some lines do not work like $this. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for php encryption, there are several encryption methods available. So don't limit yourself to CI's library. For example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

But as to your question, CI is released under the MIT license with the following limitation:

```
/**
* Copyright (c) 2014 - 2016, British Columbia Institute of Technology
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
* in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
* to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
* copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
* all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/
```

This gives you the freedom to do anything about it except for the condition above.

As to using the library:

You may copy the library here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/develop/system/libraries/Encryption.php

save as Enryption.php then create another php file:

```
include_once('Encryption.php');
$key = 'ASDFJGARLKERKL';

function log_message($message)
{
    error_log($message);
}

function config_item($what)
{
    //just a placeholder...
}
$cipher = new CI_Encryption();
$cipher->initialize(
    [
        'driver'=>'openssl',
        'key' => $key
    ]
    );
$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox';
$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);

echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertext . "\n";
echo 'plaintext: ' . $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext) . "\n";
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. However when I try loading this string to be decrypted `f3d1ff07eed0ee251a87e41dfdfb1f95ab37298a01117fb0818ad19b7c2285b931be00593f1a7e1fe81328223a97e975eb2376ebd22654a3afd0bbecb8bb6259A370tkp352snHb1fVYw3LnDz3Dxx3i8aRWyofyLn3A0=` It doesn't return anything?

Comment: Sorry for asking but how do I do that?

Comment: $key = 'ASDFJGARLKERKL';
    $cipher = new CI_Encryption();
    $cipher->initialize(['driver'=>'openssl','key'=>$key]);

Comment: This is what I did but still no return.`$cipher = new CI_Encryption();
$cipher->initialize(
    [
        'driver'=>'openssl',
        'key' => $key
    ]
    );
/*$plaintext = 'N5JJ3H3L5NBN';
$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);*/
$dec = "bd410a21c2498e83109224b38f80743b83eafcb321c7ab56e027fb84ab76708b3797ad320d011520e9811aadc67c7d13ccf9bfb45e91d757004b25efc9717266qTmIbwsXDpDtzMbQur4+KwWt7zlmvTrq8B19rDMNmR4=";

//echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertext . "\n";
echo 'plaintext: ' . $cipher->decrypt($dec) . "\n";`

Comment: I'll update my post and the decryption is still not working

Comment: 1. did you use the same key for encryption and decryption? 2. did you copy everything in the encrypted text?

Comment: 1. Yes sir I did use the same key for encryption and decryption.
2. Yes Sir I copied everything from the encrypted text since it was stored in the my personal database

Comment: Did the code above with the plaintext... encrypt(plaintext)... decrypt(encrypted) worked?

Comment: Yes sir. Sorry for that. I checked it out and yep the decrypting works if it was encrypted by that library as well. When I tried one from my storage which is also encrypted by the said library, the code above cannot decrypt it. returns none.